Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime ( DINet)
Traceback (most recent call last): File "inference.py", line 1, in  from utils.deep_speech import DeepSpeech File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Wdinet\utils\deep_speech.py", line 7, in  import tensorflow as tf File "C:\Users\Ahmed\anaconda3\envs\dinet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_init_.py", line 99, in  from tensorflow_core import * File "C:\Users\Ahmed\anaconda3\envs\dinet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core_init_.py", line 28, in  from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import File "C:\Users\Ahmed\anaconda3\envs\dinet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_init_.py", line 50, in getattr module = self.load() File "C:\Users\Ahmed\anaconda3\envs\dinet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_init.py", line 44, in _load module = importlib.import_module(self.name) File "C:\Users\Ahmed\anaconda3\envs\dinet\lib\importlib_init.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap.gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "C:\Users\Ahmed\anaconda3\envs\dinet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python_init.py", line 49, in  from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow File "C:\Users\Ahmed\anaconda3\envs\dinet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in  raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Ahmed\anaconda3\envs\dinet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in  from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import * File "C:\Users\Ahmed\anaconda3\envs\dinet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in  _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper() File "C:\Users\Ahmed\anaconda3\envs\dinet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description) File "C:\Users\Ahmed\anaconda3\envs\dinet\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module return load_dynamic(name, filename, file) File "C:\Users\Ahmed\anaconda3\envs\dinet\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic return _load(spec) ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime. See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace above this error message when asking for help.
Please if anyone can help, i m using windows 11 as a virtual machine on macbook m2

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
